# Restore node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio, node-modules

I accidentally deleted `MyProject/node_modules` folder from my solution.

Is there any way to recreate this folder?

I tried `npm install`, `npm update` but no success.

Comment: Restore it from the Recycle Bin?

Comment: Dumb that I am, I deleted permanently

Comment: I have done a permanent delete of the *node_modules* folder many times, but `npm install` brings it right back. Are you getting any errors when you run `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-check) which will search through your source code and create a list of dependancies.

If you create a new package.json (use npm init) then run dependency-check in your project directory, the file will be populated. Then simply run npm install.

Answer (score 0):

if the folder `node_modules` can't be created when you write `npm install`:

1. rename `package.json` and `package-lock.json`or delete it.I recommend rename before to delete.
2. create the empty folder `node_modules`
3. create the `package.json` writting `npm init` or `npm init -y`
4. try again `npm install` if not found try installa with a npm package example `npm i fs`